# Invalid Column Name error when attempting to use an alias Transact Sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery

What I intend to do is have an order remaining column which would be the result of the following calc:
[orderedvalue] - [totaljobvalue]

```
select [orderedvalue] = sum([ordervalue]), 
       jobtype,
       [totaljobvalue] = (select sum([total value]) 
                          from job 
                          where jobType = quotetrackerorders.jobType 
                          and reference like '%40330%')
from quotetrackerorders
where quoteref like '%40330%'
group by jobtype
```

I've tried the code below:

```
select [orderedvalue] = sum([ordervalue]), 
       jobtype,
       [totaljobvalue] = (select sum([total value]) 
                          from job 
                          where jobType = quotetrackerorders.jobType 
                          and reference like '%40330%'),
       [orderremaining] = [orderedvalue] - [totaljobvalue]
from quotetrackerorders
where quoteref like '%40330%'
group by jobtype
```

However this doesn't work because it doesn't recognise any of the aliases as columns... what can I do to achieve the following Result:

- JobType = Wall Painting
- Orderedvalue = 311654 (example value)
- TotalJobvalue = 3446 (example value)
- OrderRemaining = 64654 (example value)

Do you know how I can make SQL recognise those aliases as columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following

```
Select A.*
      ,SomeName = [orderedvalue] - [totaljobvalue]
 From (
        Select [orderedvalue] = sum([ordervalue])
              , jobtype
              , [totaljobvalue] = (select sum([total value]) 
                                   from job 
                                   where jobType = quotetrackerorders.jobType 
                                   and reference like '%40330%')
        from quotetrackerorders
        where quoteref like '%40330%'
        group by jobtype
) A
```

Comment: That seems to work, I'll need to test it further. But could you please break it down? I'd really appreciate to understand the query. Especially the A.* part

Comment: @JoséFerreira The sub-query is doing the bulk of the work.  The top query will be able to consume the results without having to duplicate the work

Comment: Cool @John Cappelletti as far as I undestand what this bit is doing: select A.* is selecting all the columns of the table A (itself)